# How to have Python3 requests library send actual Content-Length with post request instead of 0?

Tags: python, http, python-3.x, python-requests

So, I've been working on making a script that authenticates to a [NetDoT](https://osl.uoregon.edu/redmine/projects/netdot) installation. Normally, a browser will load the URL and get a 302 redirect with the cookie I want. Instead my script gets a 403 no cookie. After much debugging, which mostly consisted of packet captures and FireFox tamper-data plugin requests and trying to narrow the gap between the requests library request and the FireFox request, I was able to reproduce the problem in Firefox by making it send a Content-Length of 0, just like the requests library does.

So, now I'm trying to figure out how to have the requests library send a Content-Length of the right size instead of 0. I've searched google, but didn't find anything all that obvious. I'm using python3 with Ubuntu 14.04 in case that matters.

So, how do I have the requests library calculate and send a Content-Length of the right size instead of 0?

Here's what I'm using currently. Running wireshark shows it sending a Content-Length of 0.

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update({'referer':  'http://my.server.com/netdot/'})
b = s.post('http://my.server.com/netdot/NetdotLogin', params={'destination' : '/netdot/', 'credential_0' : 'admin', 'credential_1' : 'password'})
```

(And no, I'm not using `password` as my password, I know better, I just don't want to publicly post my password).

Comment: The requests library **does not** (normally) send a Content-Length: 0 header. Instead, it calculates the length for you, from the request body. Show us your code so we can determine what *really* happens.

Comment: @MartijnPieters updated with an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`params`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.request) argument is for passing url parameters, not for sending post content. That's why your post request has a content length of 0, because it doesn't contain any content.

To correctly pass your data as content and not as url parameters, use the `data` argument instead:

```
...
b = s.post('http://my.server.com/netdot/NetdotLogin', data={'destination' : '/netdot/', 'credential_0' : 'admin', 'credential_1' : 'password'})
...
```

Comment: Thanks! The things other people see after looking at it for just a bit after I've spent half a day wanting to bang my head against a desk...   I think I picked that up from the docs for the get method, and started with that since the post example was labelled as "advanced".